How do you display the length of specific form data on the screen when using useActionsState?
In React, when using useActionsState, if there is a nickname field, how can I display the character count of the nickname field on the screen in real-time?
Previously, I used useState to manage the nickname, and I displayed the character count in real-time by writing nickname.length inside an HTML tag. But now, I'm wondering how I can achieve the same thing when using useActionsState.
// Previously useState version
const [nickname,setNickname] = useState('');

return (
  <div>
    <input value={nickname} onChange={e=>setNickname(e.target.value}}>
    <div>{nickname.length}</div>
  </div>
)

// useActionState ?


const [state, formAction] = useActionsState(submit, initData);

return (
  <form action={formAction}>
    <input name="nickname">
    <div>  ??????????? </div>
  </form>
)



What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  useActionState still provides the state of the form values, what stops you from examining that state like any other state value?

@David I've written an example code. I want to display the form length in real-time, just like I did when using useState.

@David In the submit function, do I need to send return { length: nickname.length } by getting the nickname with const nickname = formData.get('nickname')?

When you debug and examine the runtime value of state, what does it contain?  Are you successfully updating that state in the first place?


Previously, I used useState to manage the nickname, and I
displayed the character count in real-time by writing
nickname.length inside an HTML tag. But now, I'm wondering how I can
achieve the same thing when using useActionsState.

You can't, this simply isn't possible because the action isn't called until the form is submitted.
If you want to live track the nickname input's value's length you'll still need something running in the client keeping track of the input's value and triggering component re-renders as it changes, e.g. a local React state like you used previously.
async function submit(previousState, formData) {
  const nickname = await formData.get("nickname");

  ...

  return {
    ...previousState,
    nickname,
  };
}

const initData = { nickname: "" };

function App() {
  const [state, formAction] = useActionState(submit, initData);

  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState("");

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <input
        name="nickname"
        defaultValue={state.nickname}
        onChange={(e) => setNickname(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>{nickname.length}</div>
    </form>
  );
}

